# SQL Server - How Do I Create Increments in a Query

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

First off, I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

I am moving data from one source to another.  In this particular case there is a field called SiteID.  In the source it's not a required field, but in the destination it is.  So it was my thought, when the SiteID from the source is NULL, to sort of create a SiteID "on the fly" during the query of the source data.  Something like a combination of the state plus the first 8 characters of a description field plus a ten digit number incremented.

At first I thought it might be easy to use a combination of date/time + nanoseconds but it turns out that several records can be retrieved within a nanosecond leading to duplicate SiteIDs.

My second idea was to create a table that contained an identity field plus a function that would add a record to increment the identity field and then return it (the function would also delete all records where the identity field is less than the latest saving space).  Unfortunately after I got it written, when trying to "CREATE" the function I got a notice that INSERTs are not allowed in functions.

I could (and did) convert it to a stored procedure, but stored procedures are not allowed in select queries.

So now I'm stuck.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Try it here if you dont get any answers http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I would suggest that you create a temp table with an identity column.  Then insert exec from your stored procedure to the temp table, and then finally put the data in to the actual table.

Answer (score 0):

This script may take time to execute depending on the data present in the  table, so first execute on a small sample dataset.

```
DECLARE  @TotalMissingSiteID INT = 0,
         @Counter INT = 0,
         @NewID BIGINT;
DECLARE @NewSiteIDs TABLE 
(
    SiteID BIGINT-- Check the datatype
);

SELECT @TotalMissingSiteID = COUNT(*)
FROM SourceTable
WHERE SiteID IS NULL;


WHILE(@Counter < @TotalMissingSiteID )
BEGIN

    WHILE(1 = 1)
    BEGIN

        SELECT @NewID = RAND()* 1000000000000000;-- Add your formula to generate new SiteIDs here

        -- To check if the generated SiteID is already present in the table
        IF ( ISNULL(( SELECT 1
                      FROM SourceTable
                      WHERE SiteID = @NewID),0) = 0 )
             BREAK;

    END

    INSERT INTO @NewSiteIDs (SiteID)
    VALUES (@NewID);

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END

INSERT INTO DestinationTable (SiteID)-- Add the extra columns here
SELECT ISNULL(MainTable.SiteID,NewIDs.SiteID) SiteID
FROM (
        SELECT SiteID,-- Add the extra columns here
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SiteID
                                     ORDER BY SiteID) SerialNumber
        FROM SourceTable
     ) MainTable
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SiteID,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SiteID) SerialNumber
            FROM @NewSiteIDs
           ) NewIDs
ON MainTable.SiteID IS NULL
AND MainTable.SerialNumber = NewIDs.SerialNumber
```